# Laravel: Cascade delete model if not other models share it

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So I have three models: **Post**, **Page**, and **Image**. A post and a page can share the same image, or they can have their own images.

When I delete a post, I want to delete all images related to that post, but only if those images are note related to anything else. For example, if a post has an image but it is also shared by a page, the post should not delete that image on cascade.

Here are my models:

**Post**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}
```

**Page**

```
class Page extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Image', 'imageable');
    }
}
```

**Image**

```
class Image extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\SocialPost', 'imageable');
    }

    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\SocialPublication', 'imageable');
    }
}
```

Normally, I would just do $post->images()->delete(), but I need to check first if any of those images belong to another model first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling `$post->images()->delete()`,you can listen a model delete event in `AppServiceProvider` like this

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Post::deleting(function ($post) {
            $post->images->map(function ($image) {
                if($image->pages()->count() == 0){
                    $image->delete(); //now delete 
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```